# MySQL select highest rated

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns, one called rating_average and one called rating_count.

I need to select the 3 rows with the highest rating with the rating count factored into the equation as well.

Comment: *"...with the highest rating with the rating count factored into the equation as well."* I don't follow what you mean by that. The count is an aspect of the average, it's already been "factored in" (`average = sum / count` [basically]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do math in the order by clause, like:

```
select    *
from      YourTable
order by  rating_average * rating_count DESC
limit     3
```

In MySQL, you can add `limit` at the end of a query to restrict the rowset to the first N rows.

If you'd give an example, we could probably provide you with a more specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY rating_average DESC,
         rating_count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

That gives the first 3 rows, sorted first by rating_average and then by rating_count.

Example:

```
=================================
| rating_average | rating_count |
=================================
|       9.1      |       5      |
|       8.9      |       9      |
|       8.9      |       3      |
=================================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rating_average DESC LIMIT 3
```

That may work, but you should post the schema so we can see exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to factor in the rating count exactly?  If you wanted to limit it to say items with at least 3 ratings, you could do this:

```
SELECT rating_average, rating_count
FROM mytable
WHERE rating_count > 3
ORDER BY rating_average DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rating_average and rating_count to start with but you would still like to have the results as given by Andomar, here is a complete query using only the tables 'products' and 'reviews'

```
    SELECT products.title,reviews.fk_productid,
    COUNT(reviews.review_id) AS review_count,
    AVG(reviews.rating) AS rating_average,
    COUNT(reviews.review_id) * AVG(reviews.rating) AS total_score 
    FROM reviews
    INNER JOIN products
    ON products.product_id = reviews.fk_productid
    GROUP BY fk_productid
    ORDER BY total_score DESC
```